# How can I monitor data on a serial port in Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, serial-port

I'm debugging communications with a serial device, and I need to see all the data flowing both directions.

It seems like this should be easy on Linux, where the serial port is represented by a file.  Is there some way that I can do a sort of "bi-directional tee", where I tell my program to connect to a pipe that copies the data to a file and also shuffles it to/from the actual serial port device?

I think I might even know how to write such a beast, but it seems non-trivial, especially to get all of the ioctls passed through for port configuration, etc.

Has anyone already built such a thing?  It seems too useful (for people debugging serial device drivers) not to exist already.

Comment: This might be of interest to those that struggled with the given answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic

Comment: The question is also on http://serverfault.com/questions/112957/sniff-serial-port-on-linux

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) is very useful for this. You have a visualisation of all ioctl calls, with the corresponding structure decoded. The following options seems particularly useful in your case:

> -e read=set
>
> Perform a full hexadecimal and ASCII dump of all the data read from
>   file descriptors listed in the
>   specified set. For example, to see all
>   input activity on file descriptors 3
>   and 5 use -e read=3,5. Note that this
>   is independent from the normal tracing
>   of the read(2) system call which is
>   controlled by the option -e
>   trace=read.
>
> -e write=set
>
> Perform a full hexadecimal and ASCII
>   dump of all the data written to file
>   descriptors listed in the specified
>   set. For example, to see all output
>   activity on file descriptors 3 and 5
>   use -e write=3,5. Note that this is
>   independent from the normal tracing of
>   the write(2) system call which is
>   controlled by the option -e
>   trace=write.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I knew there had to be a simple way to do this.  I use strace all the time, but hadn't even considered it for this.

Comment: That sounds great. But I wonder: How can I figure out what the relevant file descriptor number is?

Answer (score 4):

I have found [**pyserial**](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to be quite usable, so if you're into Python it shouldn't be too hard to write such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be to write an application which opened
the master side of a pty and the tty under test.  You would then
pass your tty application the slave side of the pty as the 'tty device'.

You would have to monitor the pty attributes with [`tcgetattr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) on the pty
master and call [`tcsetattr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) on the real tty, if the attributes changed.

The rest would be a simple [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) on both fd's copying data bi-directionally and copying it to a log.

Comment: How is it possible to monitor events of a change made with `tcsetattr()`? Would they be reported by listening with `select`?

Comment: The tty driver (and the os) only have a contract on select() response with input and output.   The easiest would be to just call tcgetattr() after a successful select call, before processing any input/output.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at a lot of serial sniffers. All of them are based on the idea of making a virtual serial port and sniff data from that port. However, any baud/parity/flow changes will break connection.

So, I wrote my own sniffer :). Most of the serial ports now are just USB-to-serial converters. My sniffer collects data from USB through debugfs, parse it and output to the console. Also any baudrate changes, flow control, line events, and serial errors are also recorded. The project is in the early stage of development and for now, only FTDI is supported.

http://code.google.com/p/uscmon/

Comment: This look interesting. Would be great if you could update to use any vid/pid and where to change it?

Comment: would be nice if it had a makefile

Comment: Another location is here (https://github.com/after5cst/uscmon) and issues discussion helps build it but does not seem to actually do the work  @MBR do you have an updated version or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Much like [@MBR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12595408/5798824), I was looking into serial sniffers, but the `pty`s broke the parity check. However, his sniffer was not helping me, as I'm using a CP2102, and not a FT232. So I wrote my own sniffer, by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614429/5798824), and now I have one that can record file I/O on arbitrary files: I called it [tracie](https://github.com/bence98/tracie/tree/master).

Comment: What do you mean by *"record file I/O on arbitrary files"*? Do you mean *"record serial I/O in arbitrary files"*? Or something else?

Comment: OK, we may never know. The OP may have left the building: *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*. Perhaps by some other means?